# python get specific arg

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, argparse

I got a programme with initial values:

```py
SIZE = 100
NB = 100
WIDTH_CANVAS = 150
[...]
```

But I want to allow the user to update these values from terminal:

```sh
python3 main.py NB=10
```

```sh
python3 main.py NB=10 WIDTH_CANVAS=200 SIZE=50
```

or nothing to change :

```sh
python3 main.py
```

so I tried something like that:

```py
import sys

SIZE = sys.argv[1]
NB = sys.argv[2]
WIDTH_CANVAS = sys.argv[3]
```

but the problem is: what if they don't want to specify the `NB` for example?

Comment: Check argparse - http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/argparse/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argparse` is exactly what you need. Here is a short example (https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html):

```
import argparse

SIZE = 100
NB = 100

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--NB', dest='NB', type=int, default=NB)
parser.add_argument('--SIZE', dest='SIZE', type=int, default=SIZE)


args = parser.parse_args()


print(args.SIZE)
print(args.NB)
```

So for running `python prog.py --SIZE 3` you will get:

```
3
100
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use exactly that syntax, probably set up a dict with your defaults.

```py
value = {'NB': 100, 'SIZE': 100, 'WIDTH_CANVAS': 150}

for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    if '=' in arg:
        k, v = arg.split('=', 1)
        if k not in value:
            raise KeyError('Invalid command-line argument %s' % k)
        value[k] = v
    else:
        raise MaybeGripe('Some other error here?')
```

Now go ahead and use `value['SIZE']` as you would have used the bare `SIZE` variable previously, etc.

As suggested in comments, a more common arrangement is to have command-line options and use the standard [ArgParse module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to parse them.  Maybe then your syntax would look more like

```sh
python main.py --size 25 --canvas-width 100
```

which will be more familiar and less distracting to most users.

Comment: I believe the Unix [`dd`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) command was implemented with a syntax like you propose partly as a joke. Unfortunately, it stuck, and we all swear over it.